# AS3 - Get and Set

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Why does the get and set keywords exist? They seem to be useless for me...

For example:

```
public function set player_X(x:Number):void
{
    player.x = x;
}

public function setPlayerX(x:Number):void
{
    player.x = x;
}
```

These two functions does the same thing right? And the second one does not use the set keyword.

Comment: May be: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2894249/1206613

Comment: The first function you can use like this: `object.player_X = n;` the second function you have to use like this: `object.player_x(n);`. It's simple convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the set method is implicitly called when you set a property of the same name.

You do not have to type the ( ) that do the function call but assign the value via =.

```
player_X = 5;
```

vs.

```
setPlayerX(5);
```

It can help with information hiding as to the user of a class, this is appears to be a property and can be used as such.